# How can i make the minimum Skype window size smaller?

Tags: windows, skype, window, chat

So in Skype you can either choose compact view or standard view. I like the compact because it enables me to have several chat windows open at the same time.

Problem is the default minimum window size is quite large.

When I accentually choose standard, switched back to compact and opened one of the active chats I was suddenly able to make the window even smaller (compare the Trenne Arnerholt window with the Calambor window). It seemed like the minimum size had become smaller, which is exactly what I want.

Does anyone know how to make this smaller size the default minimum size?

EDIT: using Skype version 5.8 in Windows 7

[image: Image showing the standard (Calambor) sized window and the wanted (Trenne Arnerholt) window]

Comment: @slhck ye that makes the text much more readable.. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the problem has to do with Windows 7. When opening Controll Panel ->  Appearance and Personalization -> clicking Adjust screen resolution and change the size of "text and other objects" from 125% to 100% all of the skype windows aquired the same (small) size.
Strange behaviour...

[Link to Microsofts page on Making the text on your screen larger or smaller](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller)